# I set environment variable port for heroku but later I read that heroku set this it self , how can i remove that?

Tags: heroku

I set environment variable port for heroku but later I read that heroku set this it self ,port is also not shown in environment variable in advanced system settings but shown in command line when i enter SET or ENV how can i remove that?
Because my heroku app is not running?

Answer (score 0):

If you have manually set the Heroku `PORT` env var, you need to unset it. It is dynamically set by Heroku at build time.

`heroku config:unset PORT`

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars